# Running Ubuntu on Vaio laptops

Tags: system-installation

I am an Ubuntu user... and willing to buy a laptop for my undergraduate study, but the brand which I am likely to buy does not fall on Ubuntu certified hardware. I am willing to buy **vaio S series** laptop. Can anyone answer my following questions?

1. will **Ubuntu 11.10** run smoothly with full hardware compatibility on **vaio S series** laptop?
2. is there ubuntu support for vaio or vaio support for Ubuntu?
3. googling on net found that there are some problems running Ubuntu on vaio is that true? if so will I get support from any community?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. I am flagging this for closure. Regards,

Comment: I have VPCEA1S1R and everything works ok in Kubuntu 11.10

Answer (score 0):

Partial answers:

1. Ubuntu 11.10 is not released yet. It will be released in oktober 2011 (Hence the 11.10). The most current version of Ubuntu is 11.04, however, I can't answer your question for that version.
2. I highly doubt Sony offers support for Ubuntu. However, a lot of people who use Ubuntu share whatever problems they have and the solutions they have found and did or didn't work. As far as I know there is no specific support for Vaio laptops.
3. There may well be problems, but in my experience, most problems can be fixed. "Support" for Ubuntu is provided by Canonical, where you can buy it, and the community, which provides it for free. If you are looking for a solution and you can't find it by Googling, describing your problem properly and asking kindly for a solution here, on a forum such as ubuntuforums.org or in irc (#ubuntu at irc.freenode.net) will often result in someone posting a solution to your problem

Answer (score 0):

I've had a Vaio before and at the time, the only problem there was, was with the wireless card not being recognized so not plug and play but there was a rather easy way around it.

I would suggest you go there with an Ubuntu CD, stick it in, test:
1) Sound
2) Wireless

These are usually the incompatible stuff, if it works everything else should be easy.

Answer (score 0):

I've sony vaio vpcee31fx and i used ubuntu 11.10 on flash memory, except unity all the features was good, but unity was awful, i searched the web and there is a solution to get rid of unity but still have a beautiful environment. Just right now I'm installing it on my laptop and during installation I'm surfing Internet to get to know more about it.
ubuntu 10.04 had some problems with my soundcard but this version has no problem but this version doesn't support my touchpad completely.

Answer (score 0):

My best recommendation is to stick Ubuntu 10.10. After upgrading with my VPCS11M9R to 11.10 I experience a lot of error, mistakes, a lot of functionality is raw or just missing, while 10.10 was the best. At the moment I am thinking to roll-back to the previous version.
With 11.10:
1. Bluetooth doesn't work correctly with browsing the mobile phone
2. suspending often leads to freezing and needs manual re-start
3. unity panel sometimes doesn't work properly
4. wimax is not activated bu default, in case of compiling of the stack (see linuxwimax.org) often leads to the buffer overloading and needs re-start of the network-manager
5. skype is working not good - often freezing

Canonical supports Ubuntu, but not certain laptop models. You have to seek for some proprietary drivers manually on the vendors' resources.

If you are agree to this seems minor but actually annoying little things you're welcome :)

PS I use 64-bit system with my 4GB RAM